# Qt 5.12 menu items with (unwanted) extra space

Tags: c++, qt, qmenu

Compiled with Qt 5.12 (same code as used with the Qt 5.11 version described below) my menus appear with extra space. Is there are particular reason for that, or is it maybe a Qt bug? Any chance to avoid that extra space?

5.12 version:

[image: 5.12 version]

5.11 version:

[image: 5.11 version]

Comment: Looks like it might be a regression...

Comment: If you file a bug report with the Qt devs, they may fix it for a future Qt release and/or provide you with a patch or workaround for the current Qt version.

Comment: Can you make a minimal project that reproduces the problem? Maybe it is caused by some custom styling? My own project does not have the problem Qt 5.12 on windows.

Comment: @Eelke good hint, will do, thx. Actually I was looking for a confirmation or refutation of that behavior

Comment: @Eelke, indeed as you pointed out, some style did cause it, obviously the style handling was different until then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Eelke pointed out above, it was an applied style (`qss`) that cause the behavior. Issue gone, however no idea why the style did work until 5.12 and suddenly does not anymore.

For the record: `QMenu::item { padding: 4px 25px 4px 20px; }` caused it